# Erro de sintaxe não identificado

Tags: php, banco-de-dados, syntax-error

Boa tarde. Estou tentando programar em php (sou novato), e criei uma conexão com o banco, mas quando tento cadatrar um dado no meu banco pelo meu sistema, apresenta o seguinte erro:

> Parse error: syntax error, unexpected ';' in "caminho do código" on line 24

Mas sinceramente, não consigo identificar o erro:

```
<?php

$input_quantidade_venda = $_POST['input_quantidade_venda'];

foreach ($input_quantidade_venda as $key => $value) {

    $query = "SELECT id_venda FROM vendas WHERE serial = '".mysqli_real_escape_string($serial[$key])."'LIMIT 1";

    $resultSet = $mysqli->query($query);

    if ($resultSet->num_rows == 0) {

        $query = "INSERT INTO vendas(desconto) VALUES('".mysqli_real_escape_string($value)."')";

        $insert = $mysqli->query($query);

        if (!$insert) {

            echo $mysqli->error; //Linha 24 <-
        } else {

            $output.="<p>Adicionado com Sucesso" .$serial[$key].;
        } else {

            $output.="<p>Esse dado já existe" .$mysqli->error;
        }
    }

    $mysqli->close();
}
?>
```

Comment: $output.="<p>Adicionado com Sucesso" .$serial[$key].; tente tirar este ponto, que esta antes do ;

Comment: e você esta usando 2 elses

Answer (score 0):

## Erros de sintaxe

**Primeiro**

```
$output.="<p>Adicionado com Sucesso" .$serial[$key].;
```

> Um ponto de concatenação antes do ponto e virgula sem uma string para concatenar.

**Segundo**

```
if (!$insert) {
    echo $mysqli->error; //Linha 24 <-
} else {
    $output.="<p>Adicionado com Sucesso" .$serial[$key].;
} else {
    $output.="<p>Esse dado já existe" .$mysqli->error;
}
```

> Dois elses

## Código sem erros de sintaxe

```
<?php
$input_quantidade_venda = $_POST['input_quantidade_venda'];
foreach ($input_quantidade_venda as $key => $value) {
    $query     = "SELECT id_venda FROM vendas WHERE serial = '" . mysqli_real_escape_string($serial[$key]) . "'LIMIT 1";
    $resultSet = $mysqli->query($query);
    if ($resultSet->num_rows == 0) {
        $query  = "INSERT INTO vendas(desconto) VALUES('" . mysqli_real_escape_string($value) . "')";
        $insert = $mysqli->query($query);
        if (!$insert) {
            echo $mysqli->error; //Linha 24 <-
        } else {
            $output .= "<p>Adicionado com Sucesso" . $serial[$key];
        }
    }
    $mysqli->close();
}
?>
```

> Removi um else, a estrutura condicional if só aceita um else, caso queria acrescentar mais uma condição utilize else if, exemplo:

```
<?php
if ($a > $b) {
    echo "a is bigger than b";
} elseif ($a == $b) {
    echo "a is equal to b";
} else {
    echo "a is smaller than b";
}
?>
```

[Fonte](https://secure.php.net/manual/pt_BR/control-structures.elseif.php)